# Node.js emit not working on specific socket.on

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send news to my client. On connect, it works great, but for some reason on `broadcast2` it wont get any response client sided, even know its the same piece of code, and even that `broadcast2`'s console.log is working.

***Q: How can i make sure broadcast2 emit will work?***

***This works:***

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  console.log('message gotten');
  socket.emit('news', { message: 'xxxx' });
});
```

***this wont work:***

```
socket.on('broadcast2', function (data) {
  console.log("broadcast revieced");
  socket.emit('news', { message: 'xxxx' });
});
```

this is node.js response:

[image]

total code in node.js

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  console.log('message gotten');
});

socket.on('another-message', function (data) {
  socket.emit('not-news', { hello: 'world' });
});


socket.on('broadcast2', function (data) {
  console.log("broadcast revieced");
  socket.emit('news', { message: 'xxxx' });
});
```

and this on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('mysite:8080');

function sender() {
  console.log('sending tester');
  socket.emit('sendertester', 2);
}

socket.on('connect',function(){

});



socket.on('tester', function(msg){
  console.log("callback");
});

socket.on('news', function(message) {
  console.log("INCOMMING NEWS");
  console.log(message);
});
```

UPDATE 1:

The broadcast2 socket, sent by PHP:

```
function broadcast($message,$broadcast = 'broadcast2') {
  $client = new Client(new Version1X('myurlhidden:8080'));

  $client->initialize();
  $client->emit($broadcast, ['message' => $message]);
  $client->close();
}
```

***UPDATE 2:***

**Question two: Cause my broadcast2 is sent before the client sided is loaded, and then the client connects to the node, could that be the cause?

But in the same time, im already preloading the class that holds the broadcast2 emitter.

Using codeigniter framework.**

***UPDATE 3***

I was trying to check my theory on update 2, by having two users logged in, while user one trying to perform the trigger. user two gets no output, so i suppose that theory is busted.

Comment: Where is the bit of code that sends the initial 'emit' ? Need to see that in order to make sense of the 'on' handlers.

Comment: @SPlatten updating the thread now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server cannot send a message to any socket before it is connected.  You have to wait until you have something listening to receive what you are sending.

I wouldn't call close after the emit either, as you may close the connection before the client has received the message, emit doesn't wait for the client to receive the data before returning its asynchronous.

Instead let the clients close the connections when they terminate.

Comment: so how should i fix this? ( on update4, i had user 2 connected to it and afk,  but nothing happend there neither)

Comment: If you really want to broadcast to all connected nodes then you can without sending an individual message to each client.  This may help: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Comment: can we talk in private? I have some questions regarding it, cause its emitted before the client load for me.

Comment: Yes, I can't remember how to kick off a chat session.

Comment: I cant remember, i think it have to be a long list of comments before i get the suggestion to create one. hmm

Comment: avaliable? i want to discuss it again.

Comment: Yes, what would you like to discuss?

Comment: Lets go into the chat again , where we were.